# Execute code on each node in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I want to execute something on each node using PySpark, something like this:

```
 rdd = sqlContext.read.parquet("...").rdd
 def f (i):
   import sys, socket
   return [(socket.gethostname(),sys.version)]
 vv = rdd.mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

but I don't see why I need to have to load a file for that.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sc.parallelize(range(num_executors), num_executors)` or something like that if you just want any old RDD.